# Subtitle in tufte-book

Tags: titles

I would like to add a book **subtitle** to a *tufte-book*.  Alas, I've tried several methods to add a subtitle, such as those based on the package **titling**, but all  disrupt the font, layout, author name, and so on.

My preference is to have the subtitle in the same font and style as the default in tufte-book, also left-justified, but just one or two font sizes smaller.

The addition of a subtitle must not disrupt the assignment of the title itself, which will appear in headers, footers, and other places throughout my book.

I'm using TeXShop on a Mac.

Here is minimal example:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book} 

\title{Pixels and Paintings} 

% \title{Pixels and Paintings:  {\Huge Computer image analysis in the study of art}} % gives the right appearance on the title page, but erroneously makes the full title this long version, which ruins headers and footers that contain the title

\author{David G.~Stork}  

\publisher{John Wiley \& Sons}  

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\maketitle  

\cleardoublepage

\chapter{My first chapter} 

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is what I'd like the title page to look like:

[image]

The problem, though, is that anywhere the title is re-used (e.g., in headers and footers) I get the FULL title (which includes the subtitle), all too long and with mixed font sizes and such.  All I want in these calls is the TITLE (not the subtitle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit late to the party but this works for me:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book} 

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\plainsubtitle}{}%     plain-text-only subtitle
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \gdef\@subtitle{#1}%
  \renewcommand{\plainsubtitle}{#1}% use provided plain-text title
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\hypersetup}}%
    {}% hyperref is not loaded; do nothing
    {\hypersetup{pdftitle={\plaintitle: \plainsubtitle{}}}}% set the PDF metadata title
}
\renewcommand{\maketitlepage}[0]{%
  \cleardoublepage%
  {%
  \sffamily%
  \begin{fullwidth}%
  \fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\allcaps{\thanklessauthor}}%
  \vspace{11.5pc}%
  \fontsize{36}{40}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\allcaps{\thanklesstitle}}%
  \vspace{5pc}%
  \fontsize{24}{28}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\allcaps{\plainsubtitle}}%
  \vfill%
  \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont\par\noindent\allcaps{\thanklesspublisher}%
  \end{fullwidth}%
  }
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \clearpage%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Pixels and Paintings} 
\subtitle{Computer image analysis in the study of art}

\author{David G.~Stork}  

\publisher{John Wiley \& Sons}  

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\maketitle  

\cleardoublepage

\chapter{My first chapter} 

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image: PDFLaTeX output]

Comment: I'm so glad you came "late to the game." 
 Thanks so very much.  This works perfectly!  Because the subtitle was a bit long I had to add \newline\noindent, but now all works.  (accept)

Comment: Works for me too, just exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

I just looked into the code of `tufte-book`.  It does not define an command `\subtitle` which would be perfect for your issue.

I did not find how the title is included in header/footer. Perhaps you can change your given MWE to create such an header/footer including title.

I would try simply a little hack. Define your title as you need it, for example your

```
\title{Pixels and Paintings:  {\Huge Computer image analysis in the study of art}}
```

Please see, that there are some warnings comming from `\Huge` I guess.

After building the titlepage with command `\maketitle` just change command `\title` to the short version:

```
\title{Pixels and Paintings:}
```

So with the following complete code

```
\documentclass{tufte-book} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

%\title{Pixels and Paintings} 
\title{Pixels and Paintings:  {\Huge Computer image analysis in the study of art}} % gives the right appearance on the title page, but erroneously makes the full title this long version, which ruins headers and footers that contain the title

\author{David G.~Stork}  

\publisher{John Wiley \& Sons}  

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\maketitle  

\title{Pixels and Paintings} % <========================================
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{My first chapter} 

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

I get the resulting title:

[image: resulting title]

and no distrurbing titles in header/footer (I do not see any header/footer with your given code). Please test if this workaround is okay for you.

Comment: You're right:  A **subtitle** command in the tufte-book style would solve everything... but alas does not exist.  Your clever idea a *re*defining the title after it has been printed seems to work, so +1.  If I don't get an improved answer in a day or so, I'll accept yours.  Thanks so much.